# Abbreviate "Windows 7 and higher versions"

Tags: abbreviations

In my software, I need to add a label to express "Windows 7 and higher versions". Due to the limited space, I want to abbreviate the text, meanwhile make sure the text looks official for a software product.

Below are some candidates:

1. Windows 7+(seems not formal).
2. Windows 7 and higher.
3. Windows 7 & higher.

Just wonder if there are any more ways to express the same meaning in a formal way?

THank you.

Comment: What degree of formality are you aiming for? "Windows 7+" wouldn't be suitable in an academic essay, but seems fine in a UI, especially if space is tight. Likewise you wouldn't use an ampersand (&) in formal text. It will also depend on your target audience - programmers and people with a mathematical or science background may understand 7+ more easily than other people. You can find Microsoft's guidelines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/writing-style)

Comment: Because of versions like 95 and XP, "higher" may not be the best choice. Consider using "newer" or "more recent" to convey temporal progression instead of version naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider

> Windows 7 and above

the already (by @ChrisH) suggested

> Windows 7 and later

"above", "higher", "later" in this context always is considered in terms of versions, so the suggestion that it might be considered to mean "Windows 95" is bogus.

Also your intended

> Windows 7 and higher

should do the job.

What you should avoid at all costs is to abbreviate "Windows" to "Win" - it is OK, but not "formal" - and for the same reason avoid "+" or "&".

> Windows 7 or better

because what "better" is is mere opinion. There is this old joke:

> The package said "win7 or better", so i installed Linux.

Comment: _"above", "higher", "later" in this context always is considered in terms of versions_ that might be true for people in IT (or power users) but isn't always going to be true for the general public. I'm fairly sure that there are several members of my family who couldn't put the Windows versions in their correct order.

Answer (score 2):

"Windows" in the software sense is so commonly abbreviated to "Win" that you should probably do the same.

If spelling it out in full, I would use "Windows 7 or later"; that could be a good tooltip to expand on "Win7+" which is what I'd use if space is tight.

*Win7+* is quite commonly (Google [`"win 7+" system requirements`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22win+7%252B%22+system+requirements) with or without a space before the "7" for examples) used in software specifications.

While "later" is unambiguous in the long form, "above" is quite widely used as well.

Comment: The trouble with "Win7+" is that it sounds like some sort of "extended" version of Windows 7: there's a [long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_Plus) [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordwise#Wordwise_Plus) of giving [enhanced versions](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) of [software](https://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/corel/snapfire_plus/219208/) a "plus" designation (or two!), including from [Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Plus!).

Comment: @psmears, true, but the lack of a "Windows <anything> +" for over 20 years, and specifically there being no "Windows 7 +" (or 10/11, or "plus") means this compact form isn't likely to lead to misunderstandings.  Edit coming with examples

Comment: I know there _isn't_ a Windows 7+ for people to confuse it with, but people (especially those old enough to have encountered various "Plus" editions of software) may wonder if there _was_ one that they're not familiar with. (How big a risk that is probably depends on the target audience, both in technical ability and length of memory...)

Answer (score 0):

Use this: "Windows 7 or higher."

Comment: So would that include Windows 95 and Windows 2000?

Comment: @KillingTime, as an IT person I would not understand it that way.

Comment: @KillingTime: Windows 95 is lower than Windows 7, so no.